# Add a method to a list instance in python

Tags: python

I want to add a method to a single instance of the 'list' class. Example:

```
a = [1,2]
a.first = lambda self: return self[0]
```

I know this don't work, but I want something like that works like that. I know its not a good practice, and I know I should do a whole new class, but I think this is possible in Python and haven't figured out how.

I am aware of:
[Dynamically add member function to an instance of a class in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118592/dynamically-add-member-function-to-an-instance-of-a-class-in-python)
and 
[Dynamically binding Python methods to an instance correctly binds the method names, but not the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810514/dynamically-binding-python-methods-to-an-instance-correctly-binds-the-method-name)

but none of those work with a native list.

Thanks!

Comment: note: don't use `return` for lambdas.

Comment: You want to do `a.first = lambda: a[0]` or `a.first = types.MethodType(lambda self: self[0], a)`.  If you add a function to an object like this Python won't automatically bind it to the object.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738987/extension-method-for-python-built-in-types

Answer (score 13):

Nothing will work with a native list, since you cannot add methods to a type defined in C. You will need to derive from `list` and add your method to that class.