# How do I create new methods and attributes for built-in datatypes in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to create new methods for `str` datatype. Here's what I tried

```py
class str(str):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def work(self):
        # Just for testing
        print("works")
```

Here, when I initialize strings using `str()` this  works but wrapping them around simple quotation this raises the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'work'`

Like this:

```py
b = str("Hello world")
b.work()
```

Works as intended with stdout `"works"`

but,

```py
a = "Hello world"
a.work()
```

Raises `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'work'`

I want to create new methods such that they work with these cases :

```py
"foo".work()
str("foo").work() # <- This actually works :D
bar = "foo"; bar.work()
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend not doing this in this way. Maybe create a new class `Str` that's a subclass of `str`, but don't call the subclass the same thing as the parent class, as it will only lead to confusion when reading your code, and you'll run into problems like this.

Comment: Is this in part a spelling issue? `self.words` instead of `self.works`?

Comment: The various ways in which Python creates string objects, such as quoted literals in your source code, directly call the C-language implementation of the `str` class - the name "str" is not looked up in the process, there is absolutely nothing you can do from Python code to change this behavior.

Comment: not really, the `words` was supposed to be used later. I should edit the post to avoid confusion. Thanks for the comment, @esramish.

Comment: You really can't. Is there some specific problem that you are trying to solve? There are various alternatives, but which is best depends on what you want to do.

Comment: There isn't anything that I am trying to solve. This question just arose when I tried poking around at strings and instances of `str` behaved differently from the strings that were originated from enclosing within quotations despite both being the same when I checked with `isinstance(..., str)`. I thought this was very interesting and wanted to know more, @MisterMiyagi.

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate. This is possible to do using implementation knowledge, or the ``forbiddenfruit`` package (which basically knows how these types work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit, this previously said "This can't be done, since `str` is one of the immutable types in Python. Among the immutable types are `bool`, `int`, `float`, `tuple`, `string`, `frozenset` and perhaps a few more I don't know about."

However, that's incorrect - those are types for immutable objects, but `str` (as `list` and `dict`) are built-in types and are immutable *types*.

For example:

```
def append(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print("not appending")


list.append = append

xs = []
xs.append(1)
```

Will cause the error:

```
TypeError: cannot set 'append' attribute of immutable type 'list'
```

So, although an object of type `list` is mutable, the type `list` itself is not mutable, unlike a type you might define yourself, or that was defined in one of the many packages in Python.

With other types, you might be able to do something like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __str__(self):
        return "my class"


def print_me_quoted(self):
    print(f'"{self}"')

mc_old = MyClass()
MyClass.print_me_quoted = print_me_quoted
mc_new = MyClass()

# both now have it
mc_old.print_me_quoted()
mc_new.print_me_quoted()
```

It's still a ***spectacularly bad idea***, to change the behaviour of a class by monkey-patching it like this, but it can be done. Expect your editor or IDE not to like it, or to understand it - you'll see warnings.

If you try this with `str`:

```
def print_me_quoted(self):
    print(f'"{self}"')


str.print_me_quoted = print_me_quoted
mc = str(10)
mc.print_me_quoted()
```

You get this `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: cannot set 'print_me_quoted' attribute of immutable type 'str'
```

You could do it on your own version of `str`:

```
class Str(str):
    ...


def print_me_quoted(self):
    print(f'"{self}"')


Str.print_me_quoted = print_me_quoted
mc = Str(10)
mc.print_me_quoted()
```

But of course that does not change the standard behaviour of strings - which is exactly the point.

Comment: @freekdebruijn before I go and revert your edit - how do you figure `list` to be immutable?

Comment: The `list` class is not - easily - mutable (in the context of the question), since it is defined in C. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507350/add-a-method-to-a-list-instance-in-python/7507385#7507385 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738987/extension-method-for-python-built-in-types/6739060#6739060. It is possible using the forbiddenfruit module (https://pypi.org/project/forbiddenfruit/). A `list` object is mutable.

Comment: Sorry, but that's completely besides the point here. I'm reverting the edit and would refer you to https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html: "An object’s mutability is determined by its type; for instance, numbers, strings and tuples are immutable, while dictionaries and lists are mutable." - the implementation details are immaterial.

Comment: The first paragraph is misleading. It cannot be done because `str` is a builtin type, not because strings are immutable in Python. Builtin types whose values are mutable like `list`, `set` and `dict` can't be monkeypatched like that either.

Comment: That's a good point, I'll have a look and improve the answer, thanks @Jasmijn

Comment: I realise this is what you probably meant as well @freekdebruijn, but it wasn't clear from the edit, or from the reponse - I think the answer is at least correct now, and the question has been closed due to being a duplicate anyway.